# Array empty after posting data from angular controler

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, arrays, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and angular for my app. When I post the data from angular controller to CI controller, array seems to be empty (result of print_r is "array()") .Can someone tell me why?

Angular Part:

```
$scope.posaljiKontroleru = function () {
    $scope.prosek = {kalorije: 0.0, proteini: 0.0, uh: 0.0, masti: 0.0};
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/psi/Pravljenjejela/dodajBazi',
        data: $scope.prosek
    }).then(function (res) {
        $window.location.href = "http://localhost/psi/Pravljenjejela/dodajBazi";
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
}
```

CI part

```
public function dodajBazi() {
    $info = $this->input->post();
    print_r($info);
}
```

Comment: Use your developer tools in your browser to inspect the request and see if the data is really being sent. Afterwards confirm that $this->input->post() is really the appropriate method to get that post data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  default content-type header

Try this:

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'http://localhost/psi/Pravljenjejela/dodajBazi',
   data: $scope.prosek,
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).then(function (res) {
   $window.location.href = "http://localhost/psi/Pravljenjejela/dodajBazi";
}, function (err) {
 console.log(err);
});
```